# How to convert a numeric dataframe column into a format string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert a numeric column `month` into a string, and the `month` column into two characters. Add `0` before it is not enough. What kind of sentence is used?

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
df=pd.DataFrame(np.arange(1,13),columns=['month'])
print(df)
```

```
    month
0       1
1       2
2       3
3       4
4       5
5       6
6       7
7       8
8       9
9      10
10     11
11     12
```

What I want to achieve：

```
    month
0      01
1      02
2      03
3      04
4      05
5      06
6      07
7      08
8      09
9      10
10     11
11     12
```

`Lambda` is the fastest, and I think `zfill` is simple.

```
%timeit result = df['month'].apply(lambda x: f'{x:02}')
397 µs ± 8.08 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

```
%timeit df['month']=df['month'].astype(str).str.rjust(2,'0')
764 µs ± 6.35 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

```
%timeit df['month'] = df['month'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
852 µs ± 10.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
m=df['month'].isin(list(range(10)))
df['month']=df['month'].astype(str)
df['month']=np.where(m,'0'+df['month'],df['month'])
1.2 ms ± 18.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

```
%%timeit
m=df['month'].isin(list(range(10)))
df.loc[m,'month']='0'+df.loc[m,'month'].astype(str)
1.65 ms ± 13.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could specify the [integer format](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings) when converting to a string. This could either be done by using [`.format()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) or applying [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#tut-f-strings). Using f-strings looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.arange(1,13)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['month'])
print(df)

result = df['month'].apply(lambda x: f'{x:02}')
print(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.str.zfill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.zfill.html) to

> Pad strings in the Series/Index by prepending ‘0’ characters ... Strings in the Series/Index are padded with ‘0’ characters on the left of the string to reach a total string length width.

```
df['month'] = df['month'].astype(str).str.zfill(2)
```